# Multiple SlashOptions Nextcord

Tags: discord.py, slash, nextcord

I am trying to to create a command that that allows a user to select multiple options and then put them in an embed. So far I have been able to do this with one option but I want to do it with more as well. Is there a way to add multiple SlashOptions to a slash command and if so how might it be done. Thank you for all your help.

Here is what I currently have

````
async def announce(interaction: Interaction, buysell:str = SlashOption(
        name="bto-stc",
        choices={"BTO": "BTO", "STC": "STC"}),
        stock:str,):
    embed = nextcord.Embed(description=f"**Options Entry**", color=0x00FF00)
    embed.add_field(name=f"** [️] Contract:** *{buysell}* *{stock}*", value="⠀", inline=False)

    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=False)```

Here is what I would like the end product to look like. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SmIK.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `stock` argument must be before your `choices` argument as for Python this argument is and optional argument and you can't have required arguments before optionals ones.

Also if you don't want your `buysell` argument to be optional you need to add a `required` argument set to `True` in your `SlashOption` object. And in your case you can also replace the `choices` argument in the `SlashOption`object by a list as the choices and the data you want from them are the same.

Example:

```py
async def announce(interaction: Interaction, stock:str, buysell:str = SlashOption(
        name="bto-stc",
        choices=["BTO", "STC"],
        required=True)):

    embed = nextcord.Embed(description=f"**Options Entry**", color=0x00FF00)
    embed.add_field(name=f"** [️] Contract:** *{buysell}* *{stock}*", value="⠀", inline=False)

    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=False)
```